# Having trouble creating a subdomain record on CloudFlare that will eventually point to my AWS S3 bucket’s static url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cloudflare, amazon-route53

I’m using CloudFlare as a hosting provider for my website, and AWS S3 to serve my static content. From CloudFlare I created a CNAME for my root domain (example.com) that points to my S3 bucket’s static url. This is currently working (see below).
[image]

However, when I try to set up a subdomain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) CNAME record on CloudFlare that points to my root domain (example.com) my website doesn’t render. I’ve also tried pointing the subdomain to the S3 bucket url, but that doesn't work either (because the S3 bucket name has to start with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), not example.com).

Knowing this ^, I created an S3 bucket that starts with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and redirected it to the root domain bucket that serves all the content (example.com-bucket). However, this didn’t work either.

Another theory I had was to create an AWS Route 53 hosting zone, so I did that as well (see below). However, none of the records I created in Route 53 made any impact.
[image]

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated! I’ve looked at various documentation from AWS, CloudFlare, and StackOverflow, but nothing seems to help

Comment: Why not just create a page rule in Cloudflare that forwards/redirects www to the root domain, instead of messing around with redirects inside multiple S3 buckets?

Comment: @MarkB thank you so much! I had a feeling I was overlooking something simple, but had no idea what page rules were. If you want, make a post with your suggestion so I can accept it as the answer. Also, I'm assuming I don't need AWS Route 53 anymore since CloudFlare's really the only service that points to my s3 bucket's contents?

Comment: Correct, you probably don't need Route53 any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler solution, that doesn't require creating extra S3 buckets and redirect rules in S3, is to create a page rule in Cloudflare that forwards/redirects `www` to the root domain